# How to remove my left\right padding & how to add new line to label on ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts

All my demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sinneren/ufvwkk3g/).
I do not know how to remove paddings from sides and can't find it in docs.

I added some solution for newlines in tooltips, but it still in one line. And when I try to add footer\label callbacks - it woks strange.

```
callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                var title = data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem[0]['index']]['y'] + ' РУБ\r\n';
                title.split('\n');
                var timestamp = data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem[0]['index']]['x'];
                var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
                var time = months[date.getMonth()] + ', ' + date.getFullYear();

                return title + time;
            }
        },
```

Please, can someone help with it?

Comment: Ok, for my second question I just need to use arrays in label, not title.

Comment: upd. I understand. It's hides when I use custom font styles...